# How to give a matte-finish (non-glassy) look to an image with CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

I would like to show the image with a non glassy display. Similar to the following one,

I am using the image as it is. I would like to show that with matte finish.

normal image:
[image]

Matte finish:
[image]

I am not able find it online. May be I am not using the right search keywords. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "non glassy display."  Are you talking about a matte finish vs. a glossy finish on a photo?

Comment: @Taylor714 - Yeah. I think it is matte finish. Similar to the above one

Comment: what does this have to do with css, do you wish to change the look of an existing image or something? please be more clear

Comment: @aw04 - Yeah. I would like to change the look of existing image to matte finish in css

Comment: Got it. Can you edit your question and add the actual image with the glassy display? I'm not sure how it could be done, but given the image someone could maybe help

Comment: You could put a semi-transparent layer over it to make it look more like a matte finish, but you'd really have to experiment with the color and values to try to match your image.  It sounds like something that would usually be done in Photoshop.

Comment: I still dont understand what is a non-glassy look. anyway; isnt it a question for graphicdesign.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @freestock.tk I think it is something related to css. So I dont think it will come under graphicdesign.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @aw04 - I edited the question with the images

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the difference is you're going for. I would second exactly what @Taylor714 said, either some sort of semi-transparent layer on top or a linear gradient if it's a background image would be your best bet if it has to be css.

Comment: I said graphicdesign before of this last update on the question. Now the goal is clear.

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with matte vs glossy? How is the normal image that is shown "glossy"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside a container I did put an image with **reduced contrast** / **brightness** / **saturation** plus a little bit of **blur** (all these four effects made by CSS `filter`). The image could've be placed as the container background but I wanted to apply these filters so it went separated.

After it, there's a **colored layer with transparency** covering the whole area. The letter represents the page's content that can be anything.

**UPDATE:** multiple filters must be all in a row, like it is on this latest update:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: navy;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#thepic {  
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(90%) contrast(90%) blur(2px) grayscale(10%);
  filter: brightness(90%) contrast(90%) blur(2px) grayscale(10%);  
}

#color_layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;  
  height: 100%;
  background-color: navy;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

#content {  
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #000;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#letter {
  vertical-align: middle;  
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
<img id=thepic src="http://i.imgur.com/s9J4MnI.jpg">
<div id=color_layer></div>
<span id=content><img id=letter src="http://i.imgur.com/CB1vUqy.png" alt=img><h1>&nbsp;書面</h1></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It is really helpful.  It is working as expected when I use with `id`. I am trying to use the css with the `class` instead of `id`
`<img class="background-image img-matte color_layer" alt="Background Image" src="/resources/img/side3.jpg">` Is it possible to make to use with class?

Comment: the only difference of id and class is that classes can be applied to several objects while ids are unique. On your css use **.name** when refering to a class and **#name** when refering to an id.

Comment: I used .img-matte and . color_layer in css and used in image tag. <img class="background-image img-matte color_layer" alt="Background Image" src="/resources/img/side3.jpg">. But it is not working. When I use more number of div's somehow it is introducing space between other elements.

Answer (score 2):

@freestock.tk - That's the idea I had in mind also.

Here's another way to do it with less markup:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
.container:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Original Image</h1>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WjbwTUH.jpg">
</div>

<div class="container" id="content">
  <h1> With Transparent Overlay </h1>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WjbwTUH.jpg">
</div>
```

In this example, I put the image inside a container that is relatively positioned.  The z-index is -1 so it will be behind the next layer.

Then I used a pseudo element that is absolutely positioned so it will stretch across the whole width of the container and cover the image.  The positive z-index sets it on top of the first layer.  Rather than setting an opacity, I used an rgba value for the background color.  The first three numbers or the red, green, and blue values as usual, but the last number is a decimal between 0 and 1 that sets the opacity level.  I made it a little darker than you probably want just so you can see the difference.  You may also choose a different color to fit your image.

For reference:  http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-background-image-hacks/